# How does Roblox's math.noise() deal with negative inputs?

Tags: lua, roblox, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

While messing around with noise outside of Roblox, I realized Perlin/[Simplex Noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjHzq.png) does not like negative inputs.  Remembering Roblox has a noise function, I tried there, and found out negative numbers *do* work nicely for [Roblox's math.noise()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9MZY.png).  Does anybody know how they made this work, or how to get negative numbers to work for Perlin/Simplex noise in general?

The Simplex Noise I am using (copied from [here](https://github.com/thenumbernine/lua-simplexnoise/blob/master/2d.lua) but changed to have the bitwise and operation):

```
local function bit_and(a, b) --bitwise and operation
    local p, c = 1, 0
    while a > 0 and b > 0 do
        local ra, rb = a%2, b%2

        if (ra + rb) > 1 then
            c = c + p
        end

        a = (a - ra) / 2
        b = (b - rb) / 2
        p = p * 2
    end

    return c
end

-- 2D simplex noise

local grad3 = {
    {1,1,0},{-1,1,0},{1,-1,0},{-1,-1,0},
    {1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{1,0,-1},{-1,0,-1},
    {0,1,1},{0,-1,1},{0,1,-1},{0,-1,-1}
}

local  p = {151,160,137,91,90,15,
    131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
    190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
    88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
    77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
    102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
    135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
    5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
    223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
    129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
    251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
    49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180}
local perm = {} 
for i=0,511 do
    perm[i+1] = p[bit_and(i, 255) + 1]
end

local function dot(g, ...)
    local v = {...}
    local sum = 0
    for i=1,#v do
        sum = sum + v[i] * g[i]
    end
    return sum
end

local noise = {}

function noise.produce(xin, yin)
    local n0, n1, n2    -- Noise contributions from the three corners
    -- Skew the input space to determine which simplex cell we're in
    local F2 = 0.5*(math.sqrt(3.0)-1.0)
    local s = (xin+yin)*F2; -- Hairy factor for 2D
    local i = math.floor(xin+s)
    local j = math.floor(yin+s)
    local G2 = (3.0-math.sqrt(3.0))/6.0
    local t = (i+j)*G2
    local X0 = i-t -- Unskew the cell origin back to (x,y) space
    local Y0 = j-t
    local x0 = xin-X0 -- The x,y distances from the cell origin
    local y0 = yin-Y0
    -- For the 2D case, the simplex shape is an equilateral triangle.
    -- Determine which simplex we are in.
    local i1, j1 -- Offsets for second (middle) corner of simplex in (i,j) coords
    if x0 > y0 then
        i1 = 1
        j1 = 0 -- lower triangle, XY order: (0,0)->(1,0)->(1,1)
    else
        i1 = 0
        j1 = 1
    end-- upper triangle, YX order: (0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1)
    -- A step of (1,0) in (i,j) means a step of (1-c,-c) in (x,y), and
    -- a step of (0,1) in (i,j) means a step of (-c,1-c) in (x,y), where
    -- c = (3-sqrt(3))/6
    local x1 = x0 - i1 + G2 -- Offsets for middle corner in (x,y) unskewed coords
    local y1 = y0 - j1 + G2
    local x2 = x0 - 1 + 2 * G2 -- Offsets for last corner in (x,y) unskewed coords
    local y2 = y0 - 1 + 2 * G2
    -- Work out the hashed gradient indices of the three simplex corners
    local ii = bit_and(i, 255)
    local jj = bit_and(j, 255)
    local gi0 = perm[ii + perm[jj+1]+1] % 12
    local gi1 = perm[ii + i1 + perm[jj + j1+1]+1] % 12
    local gi2 = perm[ii + 1 + perm[jj + 1+1]+1] % 12
    -- Calculate the contribution from the three corners
    local t0 = 0.5 - x0 * x0 - y0 * y0
    if t0 < 0 then
        n0 = 0.0
    else
        t0 = t0 * t0
        n0 = t0 * t0 * dot(grad3[gi0+1], x0, y0) -- (x,y) of grad3 used for 2D gradient
    end
    local t1 = 0.5 - x1 * x1 - y1 * y1
    if t1 < 0 then
        n1 = 0.0
    else
        t1 = t1 * t1
        n1 = t1 * t1 * dot(grad3[gi1+1], x1, y1)
    end
    local t2 = 0.5 - x2 * x2 - y2 * y2
    if t2 < 0 then
        n2 = 0.0
    else
        t2 = t2 * t2
        n2 = t2 * t2 * dot(grad3[gi2+1], x2, y2)
    end
    -- Add contributions from each corner to get the final noise value.
    -- The result is scaled to return values in the interval [-1,1].
    return 70.0 * (n0 + n1 + n2)
end

return noise
```

Comment: why do you ask how Roblox does it? Roblox isn't open source. How are we supposed to know the details of their noise implementations? You should rather ask how to implement this so it handles negative numbers properly. There are countless papers and implementations available online. Why ask for one that is not available?

Comment: Honestly, I used Roblox because it was easier to explain my question (it gave me pictures of working noise for negative values).  Also, I did ask how to implement it so it handles negative numbers: "Does anybody know how they made this work, _or how to get negative numbers to work for Perlin/Simplex noise in general?_"  I couldn't find anything substantial online, I found people asking questions but no real answers.  Where are you finding them?

Answer (score 0):

The Lua programming language version that Roblox uses, LuaU (or Luau), is actually open-source since November of 2021. You can find it [here](https://github.com/roblox/luau). The math library can be found in this file called [lmathlib.cpp](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/VM/src/lmathlib.cpp) and it contains the [`math.noise`](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/VM/src/lmathlib.cpp#L351-L362) function along with internal functions to calculate it, [`perlin`](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/VM/src/lmathlib.cpp#L317-L349) (main function), [`grad`](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/VM/src/lmathlib.cpp#L308-L315), [`lerp`](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/VM/src/lmathlib.cpp#L303-L306), and [`fade`](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/blob/master/VM/src/lmathlib.cpp#L298-L301). It's a quite complicated thing I can't explain myself, but I have converted it into Lua [here](https://gist.github.com/thatbirdguythatuknownot/fc1743e35bf3a760e7bc9ce9f5b50d85).